# How to include another python file from the same folder

Tags: python

I was wondering if it's possible for me to include another python file in the actual one?
I'm running an app.py from the terminal with Flask and I want, when I click on submit that python run 5 lines of code, like nothing. But when I do the variable from the first python file can't be read on the second and even if I put the same variable into the second python file then it still doesn't work.

I want to run a "for", this is the code

```
    for line in fin:
        line = re.sub('APP:NAME', name, line)
        line = re.sub('APP:USERNAME', username, line)
        line = re.sub('APP:TEXT', tweet, line)
        fout.write(line)
```

I checked all the forums and I didn't find the solution.

Thank you

Comment: I tried "import text_social" but PyCharm returns the import in grey

Comment: so your question is how to take a value of variable from one file to another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1**

I think your need is to include a python file to another python file in a same directory.
You can import a python file as shown below

```
import filename
```

here, the filename is the filename of the file in the same location without file extension.
and you can call functions inside that file by calling like this.

```
filename.function()
```

**Method 2**

if you which to rename that `filename` and use it as something else:

```
import filename as fn
```

here, the filename is the filename of the file in the same location without file extension.
and you can call functions inside that file by calling like this.

```
fn.functionName()
```

**Method 3**

or you can simply use

```
from filename import *
```

and call the functions in that file as normal functions in the current python file like

```
functionname()
```

**Method 4 (Recommended)**

or you can simply import only what is required from the file instead of entire file

```
from filename import functionname
```

and call the functions in that file as normal functions in the current python file like

```
functionname()
```